# Short-sightednes and discounting: high or hyperbolic?

Tags: discount-rate

For many years I have encountered articles that attribute behavior that strikes their respective authors as irrationally short-sighted to hyperbolic discounting. I understand why such an author might say that discounting is *high*. But as best I can tell, more ordinary exponential discounting can be set arbitrarily high (or low) by choice of the constant in the exponent. Why do some economists who wish to maintain that some behavior is short-sighted often describe the discounting as hyperbolic, and not merely high.

Comment: Any concrete examples?